NestJS Typorm Cannot Generate Migrations
List item
I am creating my first NestJs app using Typeorm
I cannot generate a migration to automatically create a migration with up() and down() methods auto generated
Here is my package.json
scripts:{
...
 "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
 "schema:sync": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs schema:sync",
 "typeorm:cache": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs cache:clear",
 "schema:drop": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/data/data-source.ts",
 "migration:create": "typeorm migration:create ./src/data/migrations/schema-update",
 "migration:generate": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate ./src/data/migrations/schema-update -d ./src/database/data-source.ts",
 "migration:show": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:show -d ./src/data/data-source.ts",
 "migration:run": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -d  ./src/data/data-source.ts",
 "migration:revert": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:revert -d ./src/data/data-source.ts",
...},
...
 "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.11.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
...

my data-source.ts located at src/data/data-source.ts
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  entities: ['src/data/entities/*.entity{.ts}'],
  migrations: ['src/data/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  dropSchema: false,
  logging: true,
  logger: 'file',
  subscribers: ['src/data/subscribers/**/*.ts'],
  migrationsTableName: 'migration_table',
});

export default AppDataSource;

my app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import AppDataSource from './data/data-source';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(AppDataSource.options),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
        entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: false,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        migrations: [__dirname + '/data/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
        seeds: [__dirname + '/data/seeds/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
        factories: [__dirname + '/factories/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
        cli: {
          migrationsDir: __dirname + '/data/migrations/',
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

I have import "reflect-metadata" in my main.js
I run in my terminal npm run migration:generate
I get the below error

> backend@0.0.1 migration:generate
> npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate ./src/data/migrations/schema-update -d ./src/databasedata/data-source.ts       
      

Error during migration generation:                
Error: Unable to open file: "D:\project\backend\src\database\data-source.ts". Cannot find module 'D:\project\backend\src\database\data-source.ts'
Require stack:
- D:\project\node_modules\typeorm\util\ImportUtils.js
- D:\project\node_modules\typeorm\commands\CommandUtils.js
- D:\project\node_modules\typeorm\commands\SchemaSyncCommand.js    
- D:\project\node_modules\typeorm\cli.js  
- D:\project\node_modules\typeorm\cli-ts-node-commonjs.js
    at Function.loadDataSource (D:\project\node_modules\src\commands\CommandUtils.ts:22:19) 
    at async Object.handler (D:\project\node_modules\src\commands\MigrationGenerateCommand.ts:78:26)
npm error Lifecycle script `migration:generate` failed with error:
npm error code 1
s /c npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate ./src/data/migrations/schema-update -d ./src/database/data-source.ts

N.B. The project workspace has the structure
project:
- frontend
- backend


From what I can see at first glance,
Your path for data-source.ts is located at src/data/data-source.ts.
You are getting an error message saying you can't open the file: "D:\project\backend\src\database\data-source.ts".
It looks like you've got data-source under your database directory, which isn't right. Try changing the path and then try generating it again.

Thanks to @mahig, there was incorrect path in package.json
 "migration:generate": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate ./src/data/migrations/schema-update -d ./src/database/data-source.ts",
had to replace database with data (well, I copied it as is from the tutorial)
but got another error saying
No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
npm error Lifecycle script `migration:generate` failed with error:

and the solution was using dist in the entities of the data-source.ts. (However, I do not know why in development I shall read the migration of dist
